# Function to check that each textbox has one entry before allowing an additional entry

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a GUI that features 12 TK text widgets, one box for each team, each widget containing the list of players within the team, when the program starts each team is empty.

The user will select a player for team one, then team two, etc.  I need a method of preventing the user from adding a second player to team one before they have chosen a player for each other team. It doesn't matter what order the teams players are chosen in, just that each team must have an equal amount of players in it before the user can proceed to the next round of picking players.

I'm really struggling to come up with a method of doing this, any advice would be greatly appreciated.  I'm fairly new here so if this isn't the sort of question this site is for, or if I've used inappropriate tags, I apologise.

Comment: Tkinter doesn't have a "textbox" widget. Are you referring to a `Text` widget or an `Entry` widget?

Comment: @BryanOakley An `Entry` widget can only handle a single line of text, so I think we can safely assume that Justin's using `Text` widgets.

Comment: Ooops, yes I meant Text, edited appropriately

Comment: Do you want to allow the user to modify or remove a name after it's been added to a list, or to change the order of the names in a list? If not, it may be simpler to display the name lists in Label widgets, and to use the Entry widget for the name input.

Answer (score 1):

If the user tries to add a player to team x, you can make sure that no team has less players than team x. Here's a way you could implement this:

```
import Tkinter as tk

teams = []

# Initialize teams with no players
for i in range(12):
    teams.append([])

def addPlayer():
    teamNumber = int(teamNumberVar.get()) #Get the team number from the entry
    #You might want to add one to team number because it will be 0-indexed
    #You might want to try/except this in case they enter something which is
    #not a number
    playerName = playerNameVar.get() #Get the player name from the entry

    #Make sure that none of the teams have a lower amount of players
    for team in teams:
    # Check if the team has fewer people
        if len(team) < len(teams[teamNumber]):
            #You can add an error message here
            return

    teams[teamNumber].append(playerName)
    texts[teamNumber].config(state=tk.NORMAL) #Set state to normal so that
    #                                       you can write in the text box
    texts[teamNumber].insert('end', playerName + '\n') #Write player's name
    texts[teamNumber].config(state=tk.DISABLED) #Set state back to disabled


root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Choose teams')

texts = []
#Create the text widgets
for i in range(12):
    text = tk.Text(root, width=30, height=10, state=tk.DISABLED)
    #tk.DISABLED means that the user can't just type into the boxes
    text.grid(row=i//4, column=i%4)
    texts.append(text)

#Create a simple menu for adding players
playerNameVar = tk.StringVar(root)

playerLabel = tk.Label(root, text='Player: ')
playerLabel.grid(row=4, column=0)

playerEntry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=playerNameVar)
playerEntry.grid(row=4, column=1)

teamNumberVar = tk.StringVar(root)

teamNumberLabel = tk.Label(root, text='Team number: ')
teamNumberLabel.grid(row=4, column=2)

teamNumberEntry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=teamNumberVar)
teamNumberEntry.grid(row=4, column=3)

addPlayerButton = tk.Button(root, text='Add player', command=addPlayer)
addPlayerButton.grid(row=5, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```